# Powerline patched fonts installed (windows putty) and symbols working with VIM, but NOT bash

Tags: powerline

Currently the bash prompt showing as colour version, but with no glyphs, i.e.:

```
?username???/???opt???path1???path2???
```

`vim` is working as expected; the correct glyph for the hard separators.

**The expected glyphs *are* visible if I `cat` the `powerline.json` files with the hard separator codes.**

Originally it wasn't displaying within vim, until I installed a patched font for for putty.  Even then it still wasn't visible on the shell prompt, however I at least go the *question marks to show* by setting the locale (see towards the end) and re-copying the main config:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/config_files/config.json
```

to

```
 ~/.config/powerline/config.json
```

Calling powerline using:

```
POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1 POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1 source /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
```

This is inside a docker instance using a centos7 image, with powerline installed using `pip` as per the setup instructions of the main powerline git repository. I did have to add the locale to the bare bones image:

```
localedef -i en_GB -c -f UTF-8 en_GB.UTF-8
```

And I changed the locale to:

```
LANG=en_GB.utf-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.utf-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.utf-8
```

I appreciate any help to try and fix this, and any tips on how to help diagnose the issue (even code edits) is appreciated.

Is it possible for instance to print out the current theme and what configuration files are being used?

It seems like this could be an issue with the render engine or perhaps an incompatibility with bash (*GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)*)?

**EDIT(1):** *Using `echo $PS1 | od -c -t x1` it looks as if the question marks are in the prompt itself.   An issue with the powerline render engine perhaps?*

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution as provided by a **ZyX-I** on github.com/powerline/powerline see the following issue I raised [a git issue on the powerline bug reporting page](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1858).

It essentially boils down to a powerline daemon that I had started before correcting the locale (`export LC_ALL=en_gb.utf8`) to be a utf8 encoding rather than the default POSIX locale that uses an ascii encoding.

For my purposes the daemon wasn't necessary, so I simply killed it, but if you use it then you will need to make sure the locale is set appropriately before executing it.  See the [raised issue for more information](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1858) mentioned previously for more information.